# Can't execute php files inside /var/www/html/[my_project]

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, kali-linux

I am running Apache as my web server on my Linux machine. I copied a folder created on Windows to `/var/www/html/` and set the necessay permissions but I can't execute the PHP files on the browser - resulting to 500 response. However when I create a new PHP file in `/var/www/html/` it runs with no problem. Running on Kali Linux.

[image: Image of ownership and permissions as they are set]

Comment: What does the Apache error log show you?

Comment: Nothing in apache error log